# how to delay redirecting to page till the data is loaded in django or jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I have a scenario as follows:

I have a search query form.

Once the form is submitted, I am re-directing to a new page (`/search/results`) to show the results.

The problem is these results are not available immediately, they have to fetched from internet (I have a function that does web scraping). Once all the data is fetched, I want to redirect to that page.

so basically
1) upon clicking the submit form, it should not re-direct immediately but wait (showing some message such as "processing your request" till the function has returned. Then redirect to that page to show the results

2) I have no idea how to signal that my function has returned.
3) I have been thinking something along these http://jsfiddle.net/DLy6j/ and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741384/delay-page-change-on-submit-jquery). But here there is a fixed delay time (hard coded like 3 sec or so). I want that delay time to be determined when my function (that does web scraping) is returned.

please share your thoughts on how to get this working

let me know if this not clear. I am using Django framework. but I guess this feature may not be possible to implement Django. But Jquery and Ajax should be helpful here.

**EDIT:**

This is my first thought:

```
   $.ajax({type: 'post',
    url: 'process_form_data',
    data: {
        html: echoHTML,
        delay: 3
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#container').html('Loading...');
    },
    success: function (markup) {
        $('#container').html(markup);
        $('#container img').on('load', function () {
            $(this).after('<div>Image loaded</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

How do I bind this jquery to submit button (I guess form action will take care of handling post data)
and how to redirect on success

Comment: Can you store the processed data somewhere in something like a database or something. It would be very easy for you to do hant you want.

Answer (score 2):

For the client side :

HTML

```
<form id="target" action="/search/results">
      <input type="text" id="searchText" />
      <div id="container"></div>
      <input type="hidden" id="searchId" name="searchId" value="">
      <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/process/search',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#container').html('Loading...');
                },
                data:{"searchText":$("#searchText").val()},
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#searchId").val(result);
                    $("#target").submit();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    $('#container').html('Search process error...'); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I am not used to django, but for the back-end, you need to check how is performed the request. 
 - Is the server holding on the http response the time performing the search 
 - Or send a 200/OK and then run the search

- In the first case, nothing to do as long as the request does not last longer than $.ajax timeout.
- The second case requires work on back-end/django side :

  . Delays the HTTP response by code to match the first case

  . Implement a websocket to allow server to "contact" client when long requests are    finished : http://blog.jupo.org/2011/08/13/real-time-web-apps-with-django-and-websockets/

**EDIT** (after comments) : The client side is edited (above). Again, I am not used to Django neither to Python, so see below some kind of server side code (NodeJs like).

Router.JS

```
//The variables below live and last with HTTPServer (!!not Request!!)
var search = require("my_super_search_module").search;

var contentProvider = require("my_super_content_provider").contentProvider ;

//Used to generate a random unique code to store search result
var guidGen = require("guidGenerator"); 

//Store search result between the two requests.
var pendingSearch = Array;

//First function called on incoming request
//route contains the url path (without domain)
//postData is parsed to object
//response would be an HTTPresponse provider
function onRequest(route,postData,response)
{
    switch(route)
    {
        case "/process/search":
             //callbackSearch function called when search finished
             function callbackSearch(error,result)
             {
                 if(error)
                 {
                   response.writeAndEnd(error.message,503,"text/json");
                   return;
                 }
                 //e.g. 3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301
                 var searchId = guidGen.generate("v4"); 
                 pendingSearch.add({"id":searchId,"search":result});
                 response.writeAndEnd(searchId ,200,"text/json");
             } 
             //Search is ran asynchronously
             search.perform(postData.searchText,callbackSearch);
        break;
        case "/search/results": 
             //Get search result in pending searchs
             searchResult = pendingSearch.find({"id":postData.searchId});
             //Merge search result in a html "canvas file
             pageSearchResult = contentProvider.merge("search_result_canvas.html",searchResult );
             //Remove pending search
             pendingSearch.remove({"id":postData.searchId});
             //Send the http response
             response.writeAndEnd(pageSearchResult ,200,"text/html");
        break;
    }
}
```

After, reading this example, it is obvious that it is a pretty complex way to do. So, I would suggest to choose between an ajax request which sends back the search results and fill a div container in the same page OR do a classic form post where the user will wait for the postback. (The actual way being a mix of both).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have thought of making the server hold on to http response for the time it is performing search. once search is finished, I want to redirect to that url. if this is the case, how should I change the success function above?

Comment: You need two requests :
- search/perform : ajax request which run the search, when the search ends, sends a JSON response like {success:"true"}.
- /search/results : classic HTTP Post which redirects the user to result.

So the only thing you need to change is the url parameter in the ajax request. The important thing is that two requests are performed one AJAX to get the search result, one HTTP classic to fetch the search results in a HTML Page.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused with your statements. if you dont mind, can you explain with an example code.

Comment: currently, I am doing classical form post, the user just waits till he is redirected (after the search is complete and data is populated). Meanwhile, I want to show something to user, like "processing your query,results will be available in few seconds". is that possible?

Comment: The code in my answer covers what you want to achieve. Unfortunately, I cannot give more details about the specific work you need to do on Django/Python side.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a 2 step process.

First, send an Ajax query to Django, for example /create-results URL.
This will execute the onSucess() function when finished, returning an ID for the results.

Second step, the onSucess() function redirects to /results?id=XXXX using the ID returned by the /create-results URL.

Comment: I am a novice in jquery. I have a template jquery I thought of. can you tune that to what you want me to do? that will be easy to follow. please see my edit above